# How to print MS-Office documents programmatically in android from SD Card?

Tags: android, android-studio, printing, ms-office, document

I have tried below code for printing the PDF file but however it is not working in MS-Office documents !

```
PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) getActivity()
                .getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);

 PrintDocumentAdapter printAdapter =
                wView.createPrintDocumentAdapter();
 String jobName = getString(R.string.app_name) + " Document";
 printManager.print(jobName, pda, null);

PrintDocumentAdapter pda = new PrintDocumentAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void onWrite(PageRange[] pages, ParcelFileDescriptor destination, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, WriteResultCallback callback) {
            InputStream input = null;
            OutputStream output = null;

            try {

                input = new FileInputStream(file);
                output = new FileOutputStream(destination.getFileDescriptor());

                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead;

                while ((bytesRead = input.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    output.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
                }

                callback.onWriteFinished(new PageRange[]{PageRange.ALL_PAGES});

            } catch (FileNotFoundException ee) {
                //Catch exception
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //Catch exception
            } finally {
                try {
                    input.close();
                    output.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

It display blank document for MS-Office files.

Please I need your help ...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`PrintDocumentAdapter` only supports PDF files, because the Android printing framework only supports PDF files. You will need to find some library or command that you can run, perhaps on your server (e.g., `unoconv`) that will convert your files to PDF format.